# on Thursday afternoon vs Thursday afternoon

Tags: word-choice, ellipsis

Are both the following sentences acceptable/grammatical?

We met on Thursday afternoon until 5 pm.

We met Thursday afternoon until 5 pm.

Answer (score 1):

Both are equally correct. Time phrases without prepositions occur in lots of different uses in English and are neither wrong nor informal.

Answer (score -2):

In "We met Thursday afternoon", "Thursday afternoon" is technically a direct object (or where a direct object would go.  Think about "We met Jim at 5 pm.")  That being said most speakers will understand what you mean by "We met Thursday afternoon."  Regardless, "We met on Thursday afternoon" is the best choice.